# Can I use Client Certificates on Azure App Services without a custom domain?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

For testing purposes I would like to enable the 'Incoming Client Certificates' option in my Azure App Service (running a WCF webservice), and see if my Client application can still connect to the webservice. Since I am still in a testing phase, my app service still has the .azurewebsites.net domain name.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get a proper client certificate that the server will accept (without switching to a custom domain name, which I know will work).

Currently, I see 2 possible routes to a solution:

1. Somehow get my hands on .cer that is signed by a CA trusted by the App Service server.
2. Generate a self-signed .pfx and .cer with my own self-signed CA. Import the pfx on the App Service and install the .cer on the client.

Both directions have not yielded any success so far. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Not sure I am understanding you well. If you want to use client cert authentication with Azure app, you can refer to [How To Configure TLS Mutual Authentication for Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth). The client cert is used for validating the client, you might use a self-signed cert. I just find this sample, [Azure Web App Client Certificate Authentication with ASP.NET Core](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2016/04/13/azure-web-app-client-certificate-authentication-with-asp-net-core-2/)

Comment: @NancyXiong: Well, the answer was in your first link: "The client certificate that is sent to the application does not go through any validation by the Azure Web Apps platform. Validating this certificate is the responsibility of the web app." So this means that any certificate will be valid as long as I don't validate anything... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, the client certificate is used by client systems to make authenticated requests to a remote server. In this case, your webservice is the remote server in a C/S mode. As you point out, "validating this certificate is the responsibility of the web app. So this means that any certificate will be valid as long as you don't validate anything". It does not effect on whether you have a custom domain or not in your web app service.

If you want to use client cert authentication with Azure app, you can refer to [How To Configure TLS Mutual Authentication for Web App.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth)

Comment: Does azure verify that the client possess the private key for the client certificate during the tls handshake?

Comment: @RobOhRob  `When forwarding the request to your app code with client certificates enabled, App Service injects an X-ARR-ClientCert request header with the client certificate. App Service does not do anything with this client certificate other than forwarding it to your app. Your app code is responsible for validating the client certificate.`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth#access-client-certificate

Comment: But TLS mutual authentication requires the server to present the client with a challenge to prove that the client is the actual owner of the certificate (the client possesses the private key) and this must occur during the TLS handshake? If this step is skipped then how is it secure?

Comment: @RobOhRob Your app will need to have info about the incoming cert you want to validate - like its thumbprint - which you can validate the incoming request against.

Comment: @JoeBrockhaus My point is it kinda defeats the purpose of TLS mutual authentication if your app is simply checking for the correct thumbprint. Although I did some testing with an Azure app service and believe azure does challenge the client to prove that they posses the private key during the request.

Answer (score 0):

If the server has requested client certificate in its server hello and the client cert has signing capability, then it is expected to send the CertificateVerify message to the server. It contains signed hash of all messages from Client Hello till that point which are buffered on the server side.  The server TLS layer will decrypt this using the client public key (which is in the Client certificate received earlier) and compare with its calculated hash. It will call back to application layer if this fails.

The application needs to handle it at that point and return its own error or continue with the session. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.8

One example of this with Wolfssl library is https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/14ef517b6113033c5fc7506a9da100e5e341bfd4/wrapper/CSharp/wolfSSL-Example-IOCallbacks/wolfSSL-Example-IOCallbacks.cs#L145