# Real MTLS (with client private key validation) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, client-certificates, azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to use MTLS to authenticate external clients to HTTP triggered Azure Functions.

However, REAL client certificate authentication doesn't seem to exist in web apps (certificate validation is done in the app itself, meaning anyone who got their hands on the certificate could have sent the request).

The full solution I'm looking for is:

1. Configure a custom CA in Azure (bonus if saving it in Key Vault is possible)
2. Client sends a request including a certificate (signed by the uploaded CA)
3. Sender is verified using the full MTLS handshake (not just certificate thumbprint)
4. If handshake doesn't complete, deny the request on the connection level.
5. Bonus - possibility to revoke a specific certificate (by thumbprint for example)

I've tried looking for an answer and this is the closest I've got (but the last comment was never answered) - [Can I use Client Certificates on Azure App Services without a custom domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53537721/can-i-use-client-certificates-on-azure-app-services-without-a-custom-domain)

Thanks!